# Prove ${2n\choose n}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

Prove ${2n\choose n}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2$

---

- **My Approach**: I will be making use of $$\tag 1\quad{m+n\choose r} = {m\choose 0}{n \choose r} + {m\choose 1}{n\choose r- 1} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + {m\choose r}{n \choose 0}$$ and $$\tag 2{a \choose b}={a\choose a-b}$$

---

By **(1)** $${2n\choose n} = {n+n\choose n}= {n\choose 0}{n\choose n}+{n\choose 1}{n\choose n-1}+\cdot\cdot\cdot + {n\choose n}{n\choose 0}$$

By **(2)** $${2n\choose n} = {n\choose 0}^2 + {n\choose 1}^2 + \cdot\cdot\cdot + {n\choose n}^2$$

Then $${2n\choose n}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2$$

---

**Please have a look at my solution and give me any hints and\or suggestions you may have.**

Comment: That's fine. If you already have (1), it is the more general formula.

Comment: Do you mean that I would be able to derive (2) from (1)?

Comment: Other than a typo in the formula following "By (1)..." it is fine (you jump straight to $r = 2$ instead of using $r = 1$ first).

Comment: @SimonRose Well spotted.

Comment: Kermit: I believe that Thomas means you can derive the initial formula you're trying to prove from (1) (as you've just shown, of course), so (1) is more general than the specific sum for $2n\choose n$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy You're right, my mistake. I'm not familiar with the procedure, should I delete this question?

Comment: @KermittheHermit There's a simpler way to format the question: have a look at the `\tag` function in LaTeX.

Comment: @Théophile Great, that's neat. My formatting was kind of embarrassing. What exactly does \quad do?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Makes sense, I see now what was meant by Thomas Andrews.

Comment: @KermittheHermit Oops, I didn't mean to leave the `\quad` in there. It's a spacing command, which I was using at first to replace several of your `\,` before realizing that the simplest way was with `\tag`. In any case, `\quad` is useful for such things as `x \in S \quad \forall x \in T`, which produces the following: $x \in S \quad \forall x \in T$. Here is an [excellent reference page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting; see item 13 for spacing. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^{l}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{l-k}=\binom{n+m}{l}$. Substituting $l,m=n$ and seeing that $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$.

Best regards.